# Substring from first found number in String with jQuery

Tags: jquery, string, frontend

What is the best way to split a String in jQuery from the first found number.

Example: `Speelhof(STE) 0 /W301`

I want to split the string in 2 parts (the split must happen on the first found number)

Result should be 2 parts:
`Speelhof(STE)` and `0 /W301`

The strings can differ with different numbers, so I would need a way to substring from any number...

Can anyone help me out? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This problem is a perfect candidate for regular expressions:

```
var match = "Speelhof(STE) 0 /W301".match(/^(.+)(\d.+)$/);
```

You can then access the two components as elements of the returned array: `match[1]` and `match[2]`.

There's no need to use jQuery here.

To explain how the pattern works: `^` denotes the beginning of the string; `(.+)` denotes one or more (`+`) of any character (`.`), and the parentheses capture this group and allow you to access it in the array that is returned. The second group comprises a digit, `\d`, followed by one or more of any character, `.+`, like in the first group. `$` denotes the end of the string.

Comment: Perfect also! Thanks for the effort!

Answer (score 3):

You don't want `.split` because it consumes the delimiter. You can use `.match` with a regular expression:

```
"Speelhof(STE) 0 /W301".match(/^(\D+)(.*)$/);
```

This will give an array with three elements: the string itself, the part that matches `\D+` (one or more non-digits) and `.*` (the rest). So you can use it as:

```
var arr = "Speelhof(STE) 0 /W301".match(/^(\D+)(.*)$/);
var first = arr[1];   // "Speelhof(STE) "
var second = arr[2];  // "0 /W301"
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have number in the string as you mentioned. You can go through the string and find the first number as a point of division of string.

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/xRRfn/)**

```
str = "Speelhof(STE) 0 /W301";

for(i=0; i < str.length; i++)
{    
    if(parseInt(str[i]) >= 0  && parseInt(str[i]) <= 9)
          break;                        
}       

firstPart = str.substring(0, i);
secondPart = str.substring(i+1, str.length);
```

Comment: This also works, although i prefer the other solutions! Way less code! Thanks!